# I think is a problem from Node but I am not sure about it

Tags: node.js, ejs

This is the error I got:

```
 TypeError: C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\views\store.ejs:81
            79|         <div class="row gallery-gird">

            80|             <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-sm-6">

         >> 81|                 <% items.music.ForEach(function(item){ %>

            82|                     <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">

            83|                 <a class="gallery-item fresco" href="img/projects/<%= item.imgName %>" data-fresco-group="projects">

            84|                     <img class="shop-item-image" src="img/projects/<%= item.imgName %>" >


        Cannot read property 'ForEach' of undefined
            at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:11:20)
            at returnedFn (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
            at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
            at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
            at View.render (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
            at tryRender (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
            at Function.render (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
            at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
            at C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\server.js:22:11
            at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:61:3)
```

This is my ejs part:

```
 <% items.music.ForEach(function(item){ %>
                            <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
                        <a class="gallery-item fresco" href="img/projects/<%= item.imgName %>" data-fresco-group="projects">
                            <img class="shop-item-image" src="img/projects/<%= item.imgName %>" >
                            <div class="gi-text">
                                <h4 class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %> </h4>
                                <span class="shop-item-price"><%= item.price / 100 %>Ron</span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">Adauga in cos</button>           </div> 
                    <% }) %>
```

And this is what I did in Node file:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey)

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/store', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).end()
    } else {
      res.render('store.ejs', {
        stripePublicKey: stripePublicKey,
        items: JSON.parse(data)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the method is `.ForEach` and not `.forEach` (note the difference in case).  I'd also suggest you add `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` to your node route handler to make absolutely sure that `items` is what you think it is.

Comment: Also be sure that "items.music" is an array add passed right to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `items.music` is an array, this is just a typo.

You need to use `forEach` instead of `ForEach`.

```
 <% items.music.forEach(function(item) { %>
```

If after fixing this issue you get the same error, then there is a problem with the `items.music` property.

Run `console.log(JSON.parse(data).music)` in the server to inspect the issue.

Comment: i got same error but now is Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Then there is a problem with the items.music property. Run console.log(JSON.parse(data).music) in the server to inspect the issue.

Comment: i got this ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PowerHell\Desktop\fanteziesiculoare\server.js:59:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

Comment: You should put it just after `fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {`.

Comment: We need the output, not the error. Try `console.log('This is my data', JSON.parse(data)) `

Comment: is solved ty but now i have another problem can we talk in private if u have time?

Comment: Join the Node.js room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209602/node-js

Comment: i have only 3 reputation